# Aligning rows by matching first elements using Cut+Insert method

Tags: excel, vba

How do I cut and insert matching rows (by shared first elements criteria)?

This question is an extension of the *Aligning rows by matching first elements* question. Upon realising VBA allows the programmer to cut+insert, it was apparent I had framed the question incorrectly. However, I have really wreaked the code trying to implement the idea. There must be a way to simplify rows below the `rmatch` function and above the nested delete row loop, to achieve the objective - I just don't know how.

```
    With wsR
        For r = startRow To wsR.Cells(.Rows.Count, t1s).End(xlUp).Row
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(t2s), wsR.Cells(r, t1s).Value) > 0 Then
    
                rMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(r, t1s).Value, .Columns(t2s), 0)
            
                .Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Value2 = "*"
            
                .Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch, t1s), wsR.Cells(rMatch, t1s + t1l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
                '.Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t1s), wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t1s + t1l)).Value2 = "*"
                .Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch, t1s), wsR.Cells(rMatch, t1s + t1l)).Value2 = .Range(wsR.Cells(r + 1, t1s), wsR.Cells(r + 1, t1s + t1l)).Value2
                
                r = r + 1
                                    
                'If .Cells(r, t1s).Value <> .Cells(r, t2s) Then
                    '.Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
                    '.Range(wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), wsR.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Value2 = "*"
                'End If
                                    
                If wsR.Cells(r, t1s).Value = "*" & wsR.Cells(r, t2s).Value = "*" Then
                    wsR.Cells(r, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                                    
            End If
        Next r
    End With
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

```
    With wsR
    For r = startRow To wsR.Cells(.Rows.Count, t1s).End(xlUp).Row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(t2s), wsR.Cells(r, t1s).Value) > 0 Then

            rMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(r, t1s).Value, .Columns(t2s), 0)
            
            .Range(.Cells(r - 1, t2s), .Cells(r - 1, t2s + t2l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
            .Range(.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), .Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Cut
            .Select
            .Range(.Cells(r, t2s), .Cells(r, t2s + t2l)).Select
            .Paste
            .Range(.Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), .Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Delete

        End If
    Next r
End With
```

So what I have done here is:

1. Insert blank cells on your table 2 on the same row as your desired value in table 1
2. Cut the cells in table 2.
3. Paste them to the blank cells.
4. Delete the old cells which are now blank.

Comment: Not quite. The algorithm is required to find matches, cut and then insert of one the pairs to align with its match. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you upload a picture of what you want to achieve? I think you have over complicated the task, but I can't wrap my head around what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, struggling to articulate adequately. I do not have sufficient reputation to reproduce the image from "aligning rows by matching first elements" (?!).Simply: imagine 2 tables A (left) and B (right) side-by-side. B is fixed, A is not and corresponding rows of A and B match, but only when the first elements of their rows are identical. To do so, A cuts and inserts its row to align with its matching B row.

Comment: Thanks that gave me a better idea of your problem.
Please have a look at my updated answer :-)

Comment: This looks better - clean. Thank you, @Matthias Fuglsang-Damgaard. Hits a 438 error 'Object doesn't support this property or method', seems connected to the .paste line … reading up on Long variables to determine cause.

Comment: yes there was an error. I have changed the answer again.
two thing:
1st: the paste-function is a sheet-function not a range-function. 

2nd: I removed r = r+1 because then you use a for-loop r will automatically increase by 1.  If you increase r by 1 in your loop as well. This will cause you to skip every second line

Comment: I hope the answer now is satisfactory :-)

Comment: Hi @Matthias Fuglsang-Damgaard. Your logic holds but a 1004 'Unable to Select property of the Range class' or 'Select method of Range class failed' pop-up, depending on the placement of .Paste after .Select. I don't fully grasp "paste-function is a sheet-function not a range-function", sorry.

Comment: right. That error comes if you try to select a range before the worksheet has been selected. just add .Select i a line. I have changed my answer again :-)

Comment: What I meant by "paste-function is a sheet-function not a range-function" is that Paste is a method in the sheet class not the range-class. So you you cannot write "YourRange.Paste" it has to be "YourSheet.Paste" else the code will break.

Comment: Hi @Matthias Fuglsang-Damgaard. Gotchya, thank you for explaining the paste-function term … Ah, the code overcomes errors but now deletes most of table 2 rows!? Based on the code's logic this makes no sense.

Comment: I just tried the code on my own computer, and it works perfectly. Could it be other parts of the code that does it?

Have you tried to set a breakpoint and go step by step to see what the code does at each line?

Comment: Hi @Matthias Fuglsang-Damgaard. I took your advice, debugged a few problems - thank you for the tip! - and then found something inexplicable. The modified code sorts the data set as expected until about halfway (coinciding with a date change in another column) and then abruptly goes "haywire" - inserting unmatched cells and, if that cell was positioned higher, shifts the column up??!